# Analytics Kit: what events are automatically collected and how to control that

Tags: analytics, huawei-mobile-services

It all started with something I read on: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/3021001

> a.    The following automatic collection events of HUAWEI Analytics Kit depend on HMS Core [..] : INSTALLAPP (app installation), UNINSTALLAPP (app uninstallation), CLEARNOTIFICATION (data deletion), INAPPPURCHASE (in-app purchase), RequestAd (ad request), DisplayAd (ad display), ClickAd (ad tapping), ObtainAdAward (ad award claiming), SIGNIN (sign-in), and SIGNOUT (sign-out).

**First question**: anyone knows the full list of events that are automatically collected?

**Second**: how can one developer have control over this? For instance: disable automatic collection.

At: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/3021008 there are mentions about `com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalyticsInstance.setAutoCollectionEnabled()` - which is deprecated - and the other `com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalyticsInstance.setAnalyticsEnabled()` is not very clear what it does.

Answer (score 1):

> First question: anyone knows the full list of events that are
> automatically collected?

You can find the full list of events [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/event_description).

> Second: how can one developer have control over this? For instance:
> disable automatic collection.

Yes [setAnalyticsEnabled](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/3021008#setAnalyticsEnabled) is the right method. As you can read in the doc:

> Whether to enable automatic event collection. The options are as
> follows. The default value is True.
>
> True: Automatic collection of system events is enabled.
>
> False: Automatic collection of system events is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> First question: anyone knows the full list of events that are
> automatically collected?

Here is the full list of [Automatically Collected Event](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-automatic-event-collection-0000001051757143-V5).

> Second: how can one developer have control over this? For instance:
> disable automatic collection.

To disable automatic collection of events, call the `com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalyticsInstance.setAnalyticsEnabled()` method.

We prefer use this interface. It provides the same function as the `com.huawei.hms.analytics.HiAnalyticsInstance.setAutoCollectionEnabled()` method, which has been deprecated because of the upgrate of SDK version.

Comment: Please update the link for predefined events in HMS Core 5: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-predefined-events-0000001051997159-V5

Answer (score 0):

```
First question: anyone knows the full list of events that are automatically collected?
```

Read following steps in the link:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/event_description#h1-1585794160367

```
Second: how can one developer have control over this? For instance: disable automatic collection.
```

setAnalyticsEnabled:
public void setAnalyticsEnabled(boolean enabled)

Specifies whether to enable data collection based on predefined tracing points. If the function is disabled, no data is recorded.

---

setAutoCollectionEnabled:
public void setAutoCollectionEnabled(boolean isEnabled)

Deprecated. The function of collecting system events is automatically enabled during initialization.